# Retrieving state data from React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, semantic-ui

I have an input form and `onSubmit`, the input value will be rendered into a `Checkbox`. The data is being stored with MongoDB - I can see the input data I've typed using Robo 3T, so I know that part is working. However, the array is empty in the console and not being added to the `Checkbox`.

```
export const QUERY_ALL_CHORES = gql`
  query chores {
    chores {
      _id
      choreBody
    }
  }
`;
```

```
resolvers.js
addChore: async (parent, args, context) => {
      // return console.log("chores: ", args.choreBody);

      if (context.user) {
        const chore = await Chore.create({
          ...args,
          choreBody: args.choreBody,
        });

        await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
          { _id: context.user._id },
          { $push: { chores: chore._id } },
          { new: true }
        );
        return chore;
      }
    },
```

Then here is my `AddChoreForm.js`

```
export default function AddChore(props) {
  const [choreBody, setBody] = useState("");
  const [addChore] = useMutation(ADD_CHORE, {
    update(cache, { data: { addChore } }) {
      try {
        const { chores } = cache.readQuery({ query: QUERY_ALL_CHORES });
        cache.writeQuery({
          query: QUERY_ALL_CHORES,
          data: { chores: [addChore, ...chores] },
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }

      // append new chore to the end of the array
      const { me } = cache.readQuery({ query: QUERY_ME });
      cache.writeQuery({
        query: QUERY_ME,
        data: { me: { ...me, chores: [...me.chores, addChore] } },
      });
    },
  });

  const handleFormSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      // add chore to database
      await addChore({
        variables: { choreBody },
      });

      // clear form value
      setBody("");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

return (
    <Container>
            <Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
              <Form.TextArea
                onChange={(event) => setBody(event.target.value)}
              />
              <Button>
                Add Chore
              </Button>
            </Form>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Then the input data should be put into a `Checkbox` here, but when I check the console, the array is empty.

```
export default function ChoreList({ chores }) {
     // get chore data
  const { choreData } = useQuery(QUERY_ALL_CHORES);
  const chores = choreData?.chores || [];
  console.log("Chores: ", chores);    

  return (
    <>
      <Container chores={chores} >
        {chores &&
          chores.map((chore) => (
            <div key={chore._id}>
              <Form>
                <Form.Field>
                  <List>
                    <List.Item>
                      <List.Content>
                        {/* {chore.choreBody} */}
                        <Checkbox label={chore.choreBody} />
                      </List.Content>
                    </List.Item>
                  </List>
                </Form.Field>
              </Form>
            </div>
          ))}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `fetchPolicy: 'network-only'` option  with your `useQuery` hook to force fetch from DB rather than apollo cache.

From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hoc/#optionsfetchpolicy):

> By default your component will try to read from the cache first, and if the full data for your query is in the cache then Apollo simply returns the data from the cache.

Comment: so like this? ```export const QUERY_ALL_CHORES = gql`
  query chores {
    chores {
      _id
      choreBody
    }
  }
` Option: { fetchpolicy: 'network-only'};```

Comment: Something like: const { choreData } = useQuery(QUERY_ALL_CHORES, { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' });...... Also, is your query returning choreData key in the result, when you run the query in graphiql playground?

Comment: That still gives me an empty array in the console, and yes, I can see all my input data in GraphQL Playground.